# wpf datagrid add user name to column being edited

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

i have form with datagrid which users can edit. one of the columns in the table is ModifiedBy. when users edit datagrid, i would like to auto populate ModifiedBy column with user UserName. 
this has to be very simple, unfortunately i am very new to WPF and cant figure it out yet

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind the `ModifiedBy` field to a string field on the bound object as normal but also use `Mode=TwoWay` for the binding.
2. Make sure the field implements the class's `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
3. Pick an editing event, either start or completion, which in the codebehind will get/update the grid's current `SelectedItem` (the instance which has `ModifiedBy`) and update that with the current user's info.

When that is changed the bound item to `ModifiedBy` will changed automatically on the screen.